# "The grass is always greener", but about "good old days"

Tags: idioms, proverbs

[The grass is always greener [on the other side [of the fence]]](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/the_grass_is_always_greener_on_the_other_side) is used when someone thinks that the place they are at is worse than some other place, but is not actually. Or when a person thinks someone else is better off, but actually isn't.

Is there a similar expression, but about "good old days"? Like when someone thinks that "the grass was greener" 30 years ago?

Comment: Carly Simon would disagree - [*These are the good old days*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticipation_(song))

Answer (score 5):

***Those were the days!***

TFD(idioms):

> **[Those were the days!](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Those+were+the+days!)**
>   something that you say which means life was better at the time in the past that you are talking about
>   We had no
>   money but we were young and madly in love. Oh, those were the days!
>
> Cambridge Idioms Dictionary, 2nd ed. Copyright © Cambridge University
>   Press 2006. Reproduced with permission.

Answer (score 4):

To quote a long ago commentator, **nostalgia** ain't what it used to be.